# Count and distinct function

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, qlikview

```
IF (A > 0, count (DISTINCT B))
```

If Variable A is greater than 0 then count variable B ignoring the duplicates with the use of distinct.

Comment: Can you please show your whole query? The question is not clear in its current form.

Comment: I want to create a query which sees whether variable a is greater than 0 and if it is then distinctly count variable B ignoring any duplicates how can I change my formula please?

Comment: See, we can't see your screen so we don't have any idea what you're talking about. Provide sample data and expected result to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

In sql:

```
count(distinct case when a>0 then b else null end)
```

In excel(using array with ctrl+shift+enter) assuming your data is found on columns A & B:

```
=SUM(IF(A:A>0,IF(FREQUENCY(B:B,B:B)>0,1),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Qlikview:

Normal expression:

```
=SUM(IF(A > 0,(DISTINCT B),0))
```

Unaffected by selections:

```
=Sum({1} IF(A > 0,(DISTINCT B),0))
```

SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN A > 0 THEN B ELSE NULL END) AS CountField
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
=Count(DISTINCT IF (A > 0, B))
```

I  would use

```
=Count(DISTINCT {<A = {>0}>} B)
```

However the latter will ignore any selections on A